# How do I suppress shell script error messages?

Tags: shell, suppress-warnings, error-suppression

In my shell script I got these lines:

```sh
rm tempfl.txt
rm tempfl2.txt
```

If these do not exist I get the error messages:

```sh
rm: tempfl2.txt: No such file or directory
rm: tempfl.txt: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to only suppress these messages even though they do not always appear, as the files might exist?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785533/command-not-found-message-is-redirected-too

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You have two options:

**Suppress `rm` warnings**

```
$ rm tempfl.txt 2> /dev/null
```

**Redirect script output to `/dev/null`**

```
$ ./myscript.sh 2> /dev/null
```

The latter has a drawback of missing all other warning messages produced by your script.

Comment: rm -f should be used carefully.

Answer (score 107):

As the other answers state, you can use `command 2> /dev/null` to throw away the error output from `command`

But what is going on here?

`>` is the operator used to redirect output. `2` is a reference to the standard error output stream, i.e. `2>` = redirect error output.

`/dev/null` is the 'null device' which just swallows any input provided to it. You can combine the two to effectively throw away output from a command.

Full reference:

- `> /dev/null` throw away **stdout**
- `1> /dev/null` throw away **stdout**
- `2> /dev/null` throw away **stderr**
- `&> /dev/null` throw away both **stdout** *and* **stderr**

Comment: Thanks. This is the first place I've seen fully explain  what the different parts of `2&>1` actually mean.

Comment: @SiHa So what does `2&>1` do? Isn't the `2` redundant here?

Comment: Please resist using `&>/dev/null` which appears to be a shorthand of `> /dev/null 2>&1`! It might not be harmful in Bash, but to clear things up: It's not POSIX compliant and always produces an exit code of 0, when using `#!/usr/bin/env sh` as a shebang on some systems. It's a better habit to use `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead. I had to learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 11):

We can use `2> /dev/null` to suppress the output error and `|| true` to ensure a success exit status:

```
rm foo
=> rm: cannot remove ‘foo’: No such file or directory

rm foo 2> /dev/null
echo $?
=> 1

rm foo 2> /dev/null || true
echo $?
=> 0
```

If you are using the command in a shell script, makefile, etc, maybe you need this.

Answer (score 8):

you should redirect all error message to /dev/null like

```
rm tempfl2.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the answers above: It is probably a better idea to keep error messages (like permission denied or some such).  Just test existence of the file before deleting it:

```
[ -f file.txt ] && rm file.txt
```

This assumes a Bourne like shell, e.g., bash.  The above has the additional benefit that it won't try to delete a directory, something `rm` can't do.

Answer (score 6):

Try this command:

```
rm -f tempfl.txt
```

the -f option acts like this:

```
-f, --force  ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

The command also doesn't report a non-zero error code in case the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you give more of an explanation for your answer?